# C# TableLayout Panel Cell Size After Adding Columns

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have winform project that it has tablelayout panel. And i added panels to all cells.

ColumnStyle property of the first and last column is absolute. Remaining columns are percentage and equal to each other.

My problem is when the user add columns i want to protect first and last column widthes.

Although I set the column widths according to the new situation, result view is not what I desired.

Codes:

TableLayoutPanel from designer.

```
// 
// tlp1
// 
this.tlp1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
this.tlp1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
this.tlp1.ColumnCount = 12;
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10F));
this.tlp1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 49F));
```

These are adding column codes:

```
    private void btn_addColumn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       int userEntry = (int)numericUpDown1.Value; // coming from user
       TableLayoutColumnStyleCollection stylesColumn = tlp1.ColumnStyles;
       int colCount = tlp1.ColumnCount;
       float lastColumnWidth = stylesColumn[colCount - 1].Width; // Last Column Width (49F) before add column 
       float newmiddleColumnWidth = 100 / ((colCount - 2) + userEntry); // new columns size of percentage
        
        
      // Adding columns to tablelayout. New columns size type Percent.
       for (int i = 0; i < userEntry; i++)
       {
        tlp1.ColumnCount = tlp1.ColumnCount + 1;
        ColumnStyle cs = new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, newmiddleColumnWidth);
        tlp1.ColumnStyles.Insert(colCount - 2, cs);
       }
       for (int i = 1; i < tlp1.ColumnCount - 1; i++)
       {
       stylesColumn[i].SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
       stylesColumn[i].Width = newmiddleColumnWidth;
       }
      // moves the panels from the old last column to the new last column
        for (int i = 0; i < tlp1.RowCount; i++)
        {
         Panel p = (Panel)tlp1.GetControlFromPosition(tlp1.ColumnCount - userEntry - 1, i);
           if(p!=null)
           tlp1.SetColumn(p, tlp1.ColumnCount - 1);
        }
    }
```

Plase help me which line i am making mistakes.
[image]

Comment: I would use the [Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutcolumnstylecollection.insert?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_TableLayoutColumnStyleCollection_Insert_System_Int32_System_Windows_Forms_ColumnStyle_) method. That should simplify the things. If you still need to move a control to another column, use the [SetColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcolumn?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_TableLayoutPanel_SetColumn_System_Windows_Forms_Control_System_Int32_) method.

Comment: @Steeeve thanx for advice. This reduced the codes lines to much. Thanx again.But the problem is not solved.

Comment: It seems, that TableLayoutPanel has a problem layouting its columns, probably rounding issues. The problem is reproducible in designer too. So you could add a second fixed size TableLayoutPanel right from your existing one with a single column and put your panels there. By the way, the performance of the TableLayoutPanel is very poor with many columns. Is there no better control that fulfills your needs?

Comment: @Steeeve. Actually 30 columns is fine. It is working nice. Tablelayoutpanel control meets what i want.  I explain in pic. Please see link [link](https://photouploads.com/image/MSIs)

Comment: @Steeeve. Is there any other controls you can recommend?

Comment: Are the controls in your TableLayoutPanel interactive in any way or are they simple pictures? I would tend to drawing them without any TLP. It would be maybe simpler and faster. Or try it with a second TLP as proposed.

Comment: They are simple pictures  but the picturebox tag property keeps info so that which items is selected. They also provides window view. Tpl last column and last row there are textboxes so user can easily enter width and heights of the items. These infos will be needed in the next processes (material cost calculation) .Without TLP how can i?